# Javascript Event Listener on click not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, events, addeventlistener

I'm trying to create one event listener to handle all my "clicks" by putting it on the body and doing some event delegation.  A simple example of what i'm trying to do is this:

```
<html>
 <body> 
  <div id = "div1">
   <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
   <ul>
  </div>
   <script>
    document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e){
     if(e.target.id == "div1"){alert("hi")}
    })
   </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

What I expect from the code above is that when I click on the "li" elements, the alert would fire since it is nested within the parent div.  I thought that the event would propagate to the parent and fire.  However, it doesn't seem to be working at all if I click on the li elements.  Can someone help explain what's happening? Thank you!

If i was to do it the normal way by adding the eventListener directly to the div id, it would then work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two elements associated with an event:

1. [event.currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget), which is the element that is actually calling the listener (i.e. the on which the listener has been attached), and
2. [event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target), which is the element on which the event actually occurred

These can be the same element, parent and child, or ancestor and descendant (which is the case here).

So a click on an LI makes it the *target*, and since the body's click handler calls the listener, it's the *currentTarget*, the DIV is neither. If you put the listener on the DIV, it will then become the *currentTarget*.

Originally, nodes other than elements could be event targets, but in recent implementations only elements are targets.

Some links:

1. [W3C DOM 4 Interface eventTarget](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#eventtarget)
2. [W3C DOM 4 Event](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-event)

Note that that *target* and *eventTarget* are specified as (host) objects, they aren't necessarily elements though that is how they are mostly implemented in current browsers.

Comment: Hi RobG, I always thought that events propagate so if I click on the element li, it would still traverse to the parent div?

Comment: Yes, but if there's no listener on the DIV it goes right by… ;-)

Comment: Thanks Rob, I appreciate the explanation.  I think I have a better understanding of it now.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `e.target.parentNode.parentNode.id =='div1'` 
See the demo:

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.parentNode.parentNode.id == "div1") {
    alert("hi")
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <ul>
```

Comment: You should post runnable snippets here, other links may not be available for as long as this post is. Also, the DIV is not the parent of the LI, the UL is so this will only be true for a click on the UL (which is difficult to do but possible), not the LI.

Comment: @RobG Thx , Is it should be  `currentTarget`  or  `parentNode.parentNode`  ?

Comment: Yes, though I have an "upTo" function that accepts a property and value so I can do `upTo(fromNode, {'id':'div1'})`, which is like jQuery's *closest*. But of course if using an ID, you'd just use *getElementById*.

Comment: @RobG Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

If you click li ,you are current 2 step childnodes from parentNode `div#div1`

```
div#div1 > ul > li[current target] //back parentNode to 2 times

<script>
    document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e){
     if(e.target.parentNode.parentNode.id == "div1"){alert("hi")}
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the LI's in your body to be clicked, you can check against the nodeName.

**Here is the fiddle:**  https://jsfiddle.net/swaprks/f3crax1q/

Javascript:

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e){
     if(e.target.nodeName == "LI"){alert("hi")}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's with jquery for reference:

```
  $("li").on('click', function(){
      var y = this.parentElement.parentElement.id;
      if (y === 'div1')
        alert(y);
  })
```

This event is attached to all `<li>` elements within the Dom. You can follow the tree towards the root with `parentElement` to access the `<li>` containing `<div>` element's `id` property.

Alternatively:

```
$("div").on('click', function(){
  var y = this.id;
  if (y === 'div1')
    alert(y);
})
```

However, this fires on every click within any `<div>` element.